# General form of invariant $(2,2)$ tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $T$ be a tensor of type $(2,2)$ which is invariant under arbitrary transformation. Find the general form of $T$.

To be honest I do not know how to solve this problem at all. But I can say for sure the following: since $T\in T_2^2(V)$ then for any matrix $C=(c_i^j)$ with $\det C\neq 0$ we have $$T_{\alpha,\beta}^{\gamma,\delta}=c_{\alpha}^i c_{\beta}^{j}d_k^{\gamma} d_l^{\delta} T_{k,l}^{i,j},$$ where $d^j_i$ are elements of matrix $D=C^{-1}$.

And probably I have to play with different matrices $C$ and find out the general form of our tensor $T$.

Can anyone show the full solution, please? I will appreciate your help and answer!

Comment: From $$\tilde T_{\alpha\ \beta}{}^{\gamma\ \delta}=
c_{\alpha}{}^i c_{\beta}{}^{j}d_k{}^{\gamma} d_l{}^{\delta} 
T_{i\ j}{}^{k\ l}$$ take $$\tilde T_{\alpha\ \beta}{}^{\alpha\ \beta}=
c_{\alpha}{}^i c_{\beta}{}^{j}d_k{}^{\alpha} d_l{}^{\beta} 
T_{i\ j}{}^{k\ l},$$ so, what do you get?

Comment: @janmarqz, I do not see yet what I can get from this relation? Could you help me, please

Comment: well, my point is that the 1st centered formula is the *exact* convention for law of how the components of a  tensor transform and the 2nd is the way to construct an *invariant*, that is, an scalar and this is $$\tilde T_{\alpha\ \beta}{}^{\alpha\ \beta}= T_{k\ l}{}^{k\ l},$$ since $d_k{}^{\alpha}c_{\alpha}{}^i=\delta^i{}_k$ and $d_l{}^{\beta}c_{\beta}{}^j=\delta^j{}_l$.